# How to declare useMutation return type in 'react-query'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-query

Given the following code:

```js
const setFriendCode = (data: Params) => api({ data })
const [mutateSetFriendCode, state] = useMutation<Response, Params>(
  setFriendCode
)
```

> Argument of type '(data: Params) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationFunction<Response, undefined>'.
> Types of parameters 'data' and 'variables' are incompatible.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Params'.ts(2345)

To avoid the compilation error I used.

```js
const setFriendCode = (data?: Params) => api({ data })
const [mutateSetFriendCode, state] = useMutation<Response, Params>(
  setFriendCode
)
```

but I want to give 'data' as a required.

How to remove the question mark on `data`?

Answer (score 18):

It looks like you are trying to match [this overload](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/69d88cca55915a1830d66465289ecc2a6e83329f/src/react/useMutation.ts#L24) (2 of 4):

```
export declare function useMutation<
  TData = unknown, 
  TError = unknown, 
  TVariables = void, 
  TContext = unknown
>(
  mutationFn: MutationFunction<TData, TVariables>, 
  options?: UseMutationOptions<TData, TError, TVariables, TContext>
): UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables, TContext>;
```

The `useMutation` hook has 4 generic type parameters.  I think you intended to use `Params` as `TVariables` but you are actually using it as `TError` when you put it in the second position of `useMutation<Response, Params>()`.  That's why you wind up with an `unknown` in the type for the `MutationFunction` which represents `TVariables`.

The signature of the function is:

```
export declare type MutationFunction<
  TData = unknown, 
  TVariables = unknown
> = (
  variables: TVariables
) => Promise<TData>;
```

---

There's not a lot of info in your question so I am filling in the blanks like this:

```
type Params = {
    something: string;
}

const api = async (args: {data: Params}): Promise<Response> => {
  return fetch('');
}

const setFriendCode = (data: Params) => api({ data })
```

You basically have two possible approaches here:

1. You can set the generics on the `useMutation` hook and include some value for `TError`

```
const object = useMutation<Response, unknown, Params>(
  setFriendCode
)
```

2. You can let the types be inferred and make sure that you have strong types for your arguments.  With the types that I put on `api` and `setFriendCode`, I get `<Response, unknown, Params, unknown>`.

```
const object = useMutation(
  setFriendCode
)
```

Answer (score -8):

useMutation does not return an array, instead it returns an object which contains several values to consume, check the following code:

```
const {
       data,
       error,
       isError,
       isIdle,
       isLoading,
       isPaused,
       isSuccess,
       mutate,
       mutateAsync,
       reset,
       status,
     } = useMutation(mutationFn, {
       mutationKey,
       onError,
       onMutate,
       onSettled,
       onSuccess,
       useErrorBoundary,
     })
```